# SonarQube 5.6 with LDAP Plugin 2.0 is unable to retrieve details for external users

Tags: ldap, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

We are trying to configure the LDAP 2.0 plugin for SonarQube 5.6 to be able to authenticate users in our AD domain. In the sonar.log we get the following feedback:

> 2016.09.12 10:55:16 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin C# / 5.3.1 / 6d9c99cb816b5d82ee23b51dbb05f9ee37a3bf2d
>   2016.09.12 10:55:16 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JavaScript / 2.11 / a9b1afa9ceef7079811779d9efc5f8026acb1400
>   2016.09.12 10:55:16 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin LDAP / 2.0 / 2910f3981167a70a201ccfae01471dfd26c794b7
>   2016.09.12 10:55:16 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Web / 2.4 / 61c14c00da36f77d18c019ad2bd7942708e99c13
>   2016.09.12 10:55:16 INFO  web[o.s.d.c.MssqlCharsetHandler] Verify that database columns are case-sensitive and accent-sensitive
>   2016.09.12 10:55:16 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
>   2016.09.12 10:55:16 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying app: ldap
>   2016.09.12 10:55:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no
>   proxy)
>   2016.09.12 10:55:18 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm: LDAP
>   2016.09.12 10:55:18 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] User mapping: LdapUserMapping{baseDn=ou=****,dc=****,dc=****,
>   request=(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName={0})),
>   realNameAttribute=Displayname, emailAttribute=mail}
>   2016.09.12 10:55:18 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] Group mapping: LdapGroupMapping{baseDn=ou=****,dc=****,dc=****, idAttribute=cn,
>   requiredUserAttributes=[dn], request=(&(objectClass=Group)(name={0}))}
>   2016.09.12 10:55:18 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection on ldap://****:389: OK
>   2016.09.12 10:55:18 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm started

The security realm is started, but login attempts never succeed. In the sonar.log we receive the following error during a login attempt:

> ERROR web[rails] Error from external users provider: exception
>   Java::OrgSonarApiUtils::SonarException: Unable to retrieve details for
>   user **** in

We've added the following configuration in sonar.properties:

```
# LDAP configuration
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url: ldap://****:389
sonar.forceAuthentication=true 
ldap.windows.compatibilityMode = true

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=***,dc=***,dc=***
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=Displayname
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

# Group Configuration
ldap.group.baseDn=ou=***,dc=***,dc=***
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=Group)(name={dn}))
```

In the adminstration we are also unable to find users. We've tested the request query (&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName={login})) using another tool and it works fine. We are wondering how we should authorize the users. Should they be available in the users page (in administration/security)?

Comment: First thing, you don't need anymore "ldap.windows.compatibilityMode = true" with LDAP 2.0, as it was used for Active Directory SSO feature. Then can you send the whole error generated during authentication ? Thanks

Comment: We are getting the following error now after increasing the log level:  2016.09.15 08:43:34 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090749, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580 ] javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090749, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580 ] 

This is the entire log:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjQuj_xHAAUnwnmJHVHaRK2n_j_Z

Comment: As said by Nico in his answer, have you provided ldap.bindDn and ldap.bindPassword ?

Answer (score 1):

Configure `ldap.bindDn` and `ldap.bindPassword` in your *sonar.properties* (see [LDAP Plugin documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin)). Without it the plugin falls back to anonymous access and in most environments the authentication attempt will therefore fail.

Note: setting `sonar.log.level=DEBUG` usually gives good details on what the underlying problem is.